# Print yes or no for even number input

Tags: python

(I am a beginner in python) I am trying to solve a python problem which is the following:

However, it doesn't pass all tests.
Help is appreciated.

This is what I managed to write:

```
choc_weight = int(input())

div = choc_weight // 2

if choc_weight % 2 == 0 and div % 2 == 0:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

EDIT: I can not see failed tests. They are hidden. The only visible test is available in the screenshot

NOTE: according to the exercise, 10 as input does NOT work because half of 10 is 5 and 5 is odd. That's why I included the div logic, so it makes sure the halving of the chocolate weight is EVEN and not ODD

Comment: what tests are not passing? you need to provide more info

Comment: Try by hand with 10 as input. Is there a valid solution (spoiler: YES, there is). Would your algorithm output YES?

Comment: Please don't post images of text; it's hard to read.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) PLease read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so the community can better help you.

Comment: It looks like you've tried to solve the problem twice over and ended up un-solving it.  Hint: get rid of `div`...

Comment: The question never asks you to divide the number in half or check each half is even. It explicitly says the halves don't even need to be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 10 as input does NOT work

But it should... I think you should focus more on this statement

> the parts do not need to be equal

Based on that statement, 10 can be made into 4 and 6 or 2 and 8... So, don't divide by two.

Other example, already given, 6 is split into 4 and 2 (so output is YES since both are even), but it's 3 by dividing by 2. Using `3 % 2 == 0` is causing you to print NO.

Therefore int-division by 2 isn't really correct.

You can also consider other cases like 4 is the first YES since nothing below can be split that way, and you can immediately exclude all odds since two even numbers must add to an even.

So, this is probably closer to what you want

```
if choc_weight < 4:
    print("NO")
elif choc_weight % 2!=0:
    print("NO")
else:
   print("YES")
```

You can also make one of the girls be greedy and take the most bar possible by giving the other girl at least `2`

```
large_piece = choc_weight - 2
if choc_weight % 2 == 0 and  (large_piece > 1 and large_piece % 2 == 0):
    # implicitly ensures choc_weight > 3
    print("YES") 
else:
    print("NO")
```

Comment: 4 should work as 4 = 2 + 2

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider the number 0 in your solution.
Did you consider negative numbers as inputs?

Also, Correctly stated by @Samwise you have to remove the `div` logic
Consider the example of 6. Here obviously you can divide it in 2 parts of even weight but since you halved it `div` is now 3 and 3 % 2 is not equal to zero

Comment: Without knowing the conventions of whatever class or platform they're using, we can only speculate if they're supposed to expect invalid input, or what to do in such a case (raise an exception?). It is a good thing to think about in general, though.

Comment: But div is necessary to ensure that the halving of the number is not odd. If the input is 10, then 10/2 = 5 which is odd. According to the if statement, if 10/2 % 5 != 0, then go to else and print "NO", which is what I want it to do.

Comment: @Anony but here you are considering the half of the weight(the input integer) and thats not correct. The question did not state that the division should be half. In last few lines it is stated that those parts need not be equal i.e. those parts need not be half, they can also be 2 & 4 if the given integer is 6 for example